# How to add meta information to aid menu search on Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: linux-mint, search, menu, file-metadata

I was wondering whether and how it is possible to add meta information to the application found when using the search box. Every time I intended to use for instance *Okular* I'd type 'PDF' to search for it but wondering why *Okular* wouldn't turn up (see image below).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way that works is via the menu configuration..

Mouse right-click on the menu  button and click *Configure..*:

[image]

Click *Open the menu editor*:
[image]

Within the opened editor, go to the application of interest and open *Properties* where additional information can be added to the *Comment* box:
[image]

Now, searching for this comment is possible via the search box:
[image]

Interesting would be still where this information is stored file-wise. That, I couldn't figure out yet. I tried using `grep` but I couldn't find any matching file with the comment.

---

<sup>DISCLAIMER: I had an epiphany while preparing my question so I provide the answer as well.</sup>